# Read an array from a non-quadratic table

Tags: python, arrays, text-files, number-formatting

I have problems reading a table which looks like this:

```
$TITLE   =                                                                     1
$SUBTITLE=                                                                     2
$LABEL   = SUBCASE - STATIC LOADS 1                                            3
$DISPLACEMENTS                                                                 4
$REAL OUTPUT                                                                   5
$SUBCASE ID =           1                                                      6
     1       G          1.100698E-02      1.961111E-03     -1.888102E-01       7
-CONT-                  0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00       8
     2       G          1.099767E-02      1.947526E-03     -1.814562E-01       9
-CONT-                  0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      10
     3       G          1.097209E-02      1.915010E-03     -1.741153E-01      11
-CONT-                  0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      12
     4       G          1.093050E-02      1.873149E-03     -1.667979E-01      13
-CONT-                  0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      14
     5       G          1.087178E-02      1.827145E-03     -1.595153E-01      15
-CONT-                  0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      16
```

What I want is to look it like this:

```
1.100698E-02      1.961111E-03     -1.888102E-01      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00
1.099767E-02      1.947526E-03     -1.814562E-01      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00
1.097209E-02      1.915010E-03     -1.741153E-01      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00
1.093050E-02      1.873149E-03     -1.667979E-01      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00
1.087178E-02      1.827145E-03     -1.595153E-01      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00
```

So I tried several things but I always had some issues.

1. First I tried to load the data via numpy.loadtxt an leave out the header lines. But I had problems getting the right data type. When I read it in with dtype=string, I couldn't convert it properly to float again.

   PunchData = loadtxt(PunchFile, skiprows=6)

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: G

2. After that I tried to use genfromtxt to fill up all the empty columns, so he can read it as a quadratic array. But I couldn't get this working, because number of columns didn't match -> number and G produces 2 columns and -cont- produces 1 column.

   kwargs = dict(dtype=float,
             skip_header=6,
             missing_values={0:" ", 1:" ", 2:" ", 3:" ", 4:" ", 5:" "},
             filling_values={0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0})
   PunchData = genfromtxt(PunchFile, **kwargs)

> ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>       Line #8 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
>       Line #10 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
>       Line #12 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
>       Line #14 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
>       Line #16 (got 5 columns instead of 6)

3. As a last approach I tried to read the data with readlines, but this ended in the same problem like the first approach. I got some strings and I couldn't convert this to a numpy array.

   f = open(PunchFile)
   lines=f.readlines()
   lines=lines[6:]
   data=[]
   for line in lines:
       data.append(line[24:])

> ['1.100698E-02      1.961111E-03     -1.888102E-01       7\n',
>    '0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00       8\n',
>    '1.099767E-02      1.947526E-03     -1.814562E-01       9\n',
>    '0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      10\n',
>    '1.097209E-02      1.915010E-03     -1.741153E-01      11\n',
>    '0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      12\n',
>    '1.093050E-02      1.873149E-03     -1.667979E-01      13\n',
>    '0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      14\n',
>    '1.087178E-02      1.827145E-03     -1.595153E-01      15\n',
>    '0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      0.000000E+00      16']

So I'm really struggling with this and don't know how to go on. Can you guys maybe help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Just process it *by hand*. You have lines containing fixed size fields with a suffix which is a line number and prefixes that can be:

- a comment indicator ($)
- a continuation line indicator (-CONT-)
- a row number and a G which you ignore

So you have to:

- skip lines starting with `$`
- keep only 72 first chars from each line
- concat a line starting with `-CONT-` to the previous one but skip 18 chars from it
- skip 24 chars from a line not starting with `-CONT-`

It yields to the following code:

```
PuchData = []
with open(PunchFile) as fd:
    old = None
    for line in fd:
        if line.startswith('$'): continue
        line = line[:72]
        if line.startswith('-CONT-'):
            old += line[18:]
        else:
            if old is not None: PuchData.append(old.split())
            old = line[24:]
    data.append(old.split())
```

Comment: Just tried the solution and it work pretty good but it took quiet long, even for this 5 rows. Is there a way to do it time-optimized?

Comment: It is weird that is lasts so long, because no really complex operation is involved. Could you give more details (platform, number of lines, elapsed time)

Comment: Ok, appearently it doesn't take long at all. It took only 0.0160000324249 s. So probably it's the Shell, which takes so long to start the script.